# IE7 Float Issue Containing Child Floats

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Float Issue in IE7</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .right { float: right; }
            .left { float: left; }
            .clear { clear: both; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="right">Right Text</div>
            <br/><br/>
            <div class="right">Right Text 2</div>
        </div>                        
        <div class="left">Left Text</div>
    <br class="clear" />
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that "Left Text" shows up after "Right Text 2" instead of being level with "Right Text" in IE7.

I've been searching for over an hour and tried numerous things, but haven't been able to fix it.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, is what you want?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hXdDu/1/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Float Issue in IE7</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .right { float: right; }
            .left { float: left; }
            .clear { clear: both; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="right">Right Text</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="left">Left Text</div>
        <br class="clear" />
        <div class="right">Right Text 2</div>                           
    <br class="clear" />
</body>
</html>​
```